# Trigger Process Builder when Contact added to Opportunity

Tags: process-builder, opportunitycontactrole

Is it possible to kickoff a Process Builder flow when a Contact is added as a Contact Role to an Opportunity? I don't see Opportunity Contact Role as an object that can be used to start the PB, so I'm wondering if there's another creative way to kick off the process?

Comment: Doubt it as triggers aren't support on Opportunity Contact Roles either.

Comment: @Girbot I wonder how many eager junior product managers come to SFDC to enable OCR as a trigger-able object only to discover that it will  be on the roadmap for 2050 ?  This limitation has been around for so long

Comment: One way to do it is to have a batch process evaluate new OCR records and do what you need to when you find a new one. Not ideal, or real time, but kinda what we are stuck with

Comment: @Eric how would you query just the new OCR records? Didn't see any sort of created date to base the SOQL on for batch process.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone in the comments said, creating Apex Triggers on the Opportunity Contact Role is not currently a functionality offered by Salesforce. There is currently an Idea on the community for this if you would like to go vote for it [here.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrdvAAC) The other option is to run a query through Apex. Unfortunately this is not real time like Eric said.

We have been trying to get this for years and I have had to come up with numerous workarounds for different clients because of this lack of functionality. Best of luck!

Comment: Why is this an answer? It just restates what is in the comments

Comment: Wanted to summarize everything so a best answer could be selected so we can keep the community clean. Also, wanted to provide the link to the idea that OP could go and vote for so we can get this functionality changed.

Comment: I can remove it if you believe it is not necessary. You have the reputation seniority lol

Comment: Nah. Let community decide. I am just one person

Comment: You might want to just make it a wiki if you're simply summarizing comments.